# how to use the table name dynamically for insert, update operations using petapoco

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, petapoco

I have a situation where I need to dynamically give the name of table for which table is being updated. The table name some how I obtain.I want to do something like this.

```
string tableName="Template";
dataContext.Update(tableName, "Id", newuser);
```

How is it possible?Please Help!!

Comment: What you've provided (which isn't much) looks fine. What error are you getting?

Comment: Do you mean determining table name by POCO type in generic method?